# Need help understanding LINQ in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am quite new to MVC from webforms and it has been a really, really steep learning curve for me. Here is the function in the tutorial that I am following:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    string searchString = id;
    var movies = from m in db.Movies
                 select m;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }
    return View(movies);
}
```

Here is what I think I know that is happening. The method being an Action result(without parameters) re returning a view. The parameters are added to tell the application to look for a "id" string.

I find the lambda statement a little easier to understand. The `if` is checking to see if the `searchString` is null if not it returns the movie that matches the description in `searchString`.

In the method however, `searchString` is given the value of `id` in the parameter. Here is where I start getting lost, right after `searchString` is defined, a LINQ statement is placed inside the variable `movies`. In that statement, what is the purpose of `m`? Why is it not defined or is it? The same with the `s` in the lambda.

Comment: I believe it's equivalent to `var movies = db.Movies.Select(m => m)`, which is (logically, at least) a no-op (but it depends on the LINQ provider, I'd guess). Basically, this whole things says: "Select all movies, unless there's a search string - in which case, only keep movies that contain that search string."

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis what I understand out of your comment is Select from Movies where m is greater or equal to m....im guessing m is also partially defined by the searchString. correct? What do you mean by no-op?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis it's a setup to get the right type for `var`. `db.Movies` is most likely a `DbSet<>` which wouldn't allow for the where to be appended.

Comment: @Skullomania The `=>` symbol is not the `>=` (greater-or-equal) operator. It's the symbol that denotes a lambda in C#. If you don't know what lambdas are and how they work (at least in C#) and how LINQ works with them, try learning LINQ out of ASP.NET MVC first (because the framework is hard enough to learn even without having to worry about LINQ).

Comment: @Johnbot True, but a more sane alternative would have been to write `var movies = db.Movies as IQueryable<Movie>`, or even `IQueryable<Movie> movies = db.Movies`, instead of writing a whole LINQ expression (and whatever anonymous code it generates) just to assign to a super type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `m` and `s` are implicitly typed. Since you are selecting `m` from `movies`, you don't need to tell LINQ what `m` is. It can imply the type by looking at what `db.Movies` is a collection of. So if `db.Movies` was `IEnumerable<Movie>` (for example) then `m` would be a `Movie`.

There is nothing to stop you from specifying the type if you really want to, so you could type:

```
 var movies = from Movie m in db.Movies
             select m;
```

But you rarely need to.

Note you are also implicitly typing `movies`, it's the same concept. So long as the compiler can unambiguously figure out what the type should be.

Answer (score 4):

The variables `m` and `s` are variables for each instance of `Movie` within the `db.Movies` "collection" (I assume that's what the class is called).

Conceptually these are similar to using and sql alias `m` in the following sql:

```
select m.* from Movies m
```

When you later apply the `where` clause you're conceptually ending up with:

```
select * from (
    select m.* from Movies m
) s
where s.Title like '%' + searchString + '%'
```

NOTE that this isn't how the sql actually ends up when it runs against the database, just a representation to aid understanding.

If you look at the value of `movies` then you'll see that it is an `IQueryable` or similar. This means that it hasn't actually executed yet - you've not returned anything. So adding the `where` clause later is fine - it just gets added to the query that'll get run later.

Answer (score 2):

`var movies = from m in db.Movies select m` roughly translates to "Take all items in db.Movies and name them temporarily m, then return them in an IEnumerable". Indeed you'll see that `movies` is of type `IEnumerable<Movie>`.

The same goes for `movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));`: For all items in movies, name them temporarily `s` and return those whose `Title` contains your `searchString` as an `IEnumerable`.

I hope it became a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I'll try to explain what's happening:

with:

```
var movies = from m in db.Movies select m;
```

You are describing a way of processing the collection 'db.Movies' (whatever that is...)

In descriptive language:

1) `in dbo.Movies` We are going to be inspecting/looping over everything everything in db.Movies.

2) `from m` As we go over them, 1-by-1 we'll store each thing we come across in a variable called 'm' for further use in the expression.

3) `select m` Ok - we want this query / expression to actually return something - to actually yield some results - so, lets 1-by-1 just return the 'm' we declared earlier

Answer (score 0):

The variables `m` and `s` are using the `var` keywords which means that you don't have to explicitly mention the type of the variable.  The compiler figures it out for you.  It's basically a variable of the `IEnumerable` type.

The `var` keyword is generally useful in the following when you cannot explicitly define the return type of `movies` as shown below-

```
var movies = from m in db.Movies
             select new { m.Attr1, m.Attr2 } ;
```

Since, the clause within `new` is another 'anonymous' object not specified anywhere, you need the `var` keyword.